# Swift - Firebase Error, How to Access to First Child

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase now and I got stuck with this.

I have a contactList like below.

[image]

I want to get the keys (like "-L8per5UdCjQyCBxs5Oo" for the one) but I don't know how to do this.

I tried something like this:

```
guard let contactList = self.user?.contactList else { return }
print(contactList[0])
```

And the error message is this.

```
Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : [String : String]]' with an index of type 'Int'
```

How can I fix this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you want to do with the keys? Print them? Add them to an array? Is the userId important during this task or are you just interested in the keys. Do you want to observe additional keys that are added ongoing to just do this once, i.e. only when a user clicks a button? Are there millions of contacts or a few hundred? There are a number of answers but the question is a bit vague.

Answer (score 1):

```
var ref:DatabaseReference?
var contactListArray:[DataSnapshot] = []  //you could create an array to save your children

func startListening() {
  ref = Database.database().reference().child("contactList")
  ref?.observe(.childAdded) {(snapshot) in
    self.contactListArray.append(snapshot) // doing this, you can access the first child by contactListArray[0]

    // This is how to access info in your snapshot if you need it

    let key = snapshot.key //HERE: you'll get the keys
    let props = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    let userId = props["userId"] //HERE: how to access to data
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through fetched objects via:

```
for (key, value) in contactList {
    ///
}
```

If you want to get the first object, you can write:

```
contactList.first
```